# Overlapping instance for Show

Tags: haskell, overlapping-instances

Suppose we have the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Sample where

newtype A a =
  A a
  deriving (Show)

newtype L a =
  L [a]

class ListContainer l where
  getList :: l a -> [a]

instance ListContainer L where
  getList (L l) = l

instance (Show a, ListContainer l) => Show (l a) where
  show = const "example"
```

With this code, ghc complains:

```
warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
• Overlapping instances for Show (A a)
    arising from a use of ‘GHC.Show.$dmshowList’
  Matching instances:
    instance (Show a, ListContainer l) => Show (l a)
      -- Defined at /.../src/Sample.hs:18:10
    instance Show a => Show (A a)
      -- Defined at /.../src/Sample.hs:7:13
• In the expression: GHC.Show.$dmshowList @(A a)
  In an equation for ‘showList’:
      showList = GHC.Show.$dmshowList @(A a)
  When typechecking the code for ‘showList’
    in a derived instance for ‘Show (A a)’:
    To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
  In the instance declaration for ‘Show (A a)’
warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
• Overlapping instances for Show (A a)
    arising from a use of ‘GHC.Show.$dmshow’
  Matching instances:
    instance (Show a, ListContainer l) => Show (l a)
      -- Defined at /.../src/Sample.hs:18:10
    instance Show a => Show (A a)
      -- Defined at /.../src/Sample.hs:7:13
• In the expression: GHC.Show.$dmshow @(A a)
  In an equation for ‘show’: show = GHC.Show.$dmshow @(A a)
  When typechecking the code for ‘show’
    in a derived instance for ‘Show (A a)’:
    To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
  In the instance declaration for ‘Show (A a)’
```

I can understand that it thinks type `a` can either derive `Show`, or derive `ListContainer`, which may result in `Show`.

How do we avoid that?

I understand that there exists a function `showList`, but its signature is a bit foreign. I do already have a function that I intend to use to display certain lists, which returns `String` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can understand that it thinks type `a` can either derive `Show`, or derive `ListContainer`, which may result in `Show`.

That is not what it thinks.

When Haskell chooses class instance, it doesn't look at instance constraints at all. All it considers when choosing an instance is the instance head (the thing that comes right after class name).

In your `Show` instance, the instance head is `l a`. This instance head matches `A a` (by assuming `l = A`). It also matches a lot of other things by the way - for example, it matches `Maybe a` (where `l = Maybe`), and `Either b a` (with `l = Either b`), and `Identity a`, and `IO a` - pretty much every type with a type parameter, come to think of it. It doesn't matter that neither `A` nor `Maybe` nor `IO` have an instance of `ListContainer`, because like I said above, Haskell doesn't look at constraints when choosing instances, only at instance heads.

It is only *after* finding a matching instance (by matching on its head) that Haskell will check if that instance's constraints are in fact satisfied. And will complain if they aren't. But it will never go back and try to pick another instance instead.

So coming back to your example: since `A` now has two matching `Show` instances - its own derived one and the `Show (l a)` one that you wrote, - the compiler complains that they are overlapping.

Comment: This seems like unfortunate and unintuitive behaviour, at least from the perspective of the user. Is there are good reason that ghc works this way?

Comment: If instances were chosen based on constraints, then the result would depend on which instances are in scope, which would be super fragile. For example, the meaning of your program could change if you add an import of a seemingly unrelated module that just happens to contain an instance. Or even without changing your imports, but instead upgrading dependencies. This would be hell to debug.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you can just remove `instance (Show a, ListContainer l) => Show (l a)` and add `deriving (Show)` to `L` definition.

Alternatively you can remove `deriving (Show)` from `A` definition.

If you want you code behave as it is now remove `deriving (Show)` and implement it explicitly

```
 instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-}  Show a => Show (A a)
      where 
         show (A a) = "A " ++ show a
```